# Gauge/ Scatter charts showing horizontal lines for large data at one point(qliksense limitation)

Tags: data-visualization, scatter, qliksense, gauge

While working on Qliksense, Gauge/Scatter chart is showing horizontal line for large data at one point. Currently, the limitation is if there are more than 1000 data values at any given point in the scatter chart will show as horizontal line at one point. Is there any alternative way to resolve this issue for large data in Qliksense

Comment: can you share screenshot of gauge, expression and sample dataset. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.